# Importin Excel files in xls format

Tags: import, excel

Does anybody know if it's possible to import .xls files into SFMC ?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it doesn't support xls files.

> Format: When you create the file of subscriber data to be imported
>   into the application, save it as a tab-delimited .txt file or a
>   comma-delimited .csv file. Many applications, such as Excel, offer
>   these formats.

Source: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscriber_import_file_requirements.htm&type=5